# What is the purpose of the <figure> element?

Tags: html, figure

I have been trying to understand the `<figure>` element; take a look at this from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element):

> Self-contained in this context does not necessarily mean independent. For example,each sentence in a paragraph is self-contained; an image that is part of a sentence would be inappropriate for figure, but an entire sentence made of images would be fitting.

How can an image can be part of a sentence? What is this talking about? I have read many explanations, but yet I don't understand why I would want to use this element. What is the purpose of this tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML5 semantic tags are cryptic for everyone. Since the concepts are kept abstract and scientific in purpose, I will use a bunch of over-simplification to make it understandable, in spite of HTML5 
gurus telling me how wrong I am.

Remember that semantic tags are created to be read by **computers**, not humans. They exist so that google's scripts (and everyone's scripts, but mainly google and hacker bots) can quickly search for figures and index them. To understand semantic tags, think like a script, not as a human.

> "If I was a bot programmed by a hacker, how would I mine figures when crawling my website?"

If we code a script that looks for IMG tags it will end up gathering a bunch of garbage (i.e. icons). What we're interested in is real content, that's what "**self-contained content**" means: you cut & paste this element from your website into my gallery of mined images in your HTML, and it's useful.

**Garbage:** icons, decorative images, images created by javascript plugins to prettify things, smileys, etc.

**Good finds:** charts, photos, diagrams, maps, drawings, etc.

The "*Good finds*" make sense even if you steal them from your webpage with no context whatsoever, except things like the accompanying "caption" tag. These tags allow crawlers to associate your images with text tags, making categorization easier **So you don't want to miss this content**.

So we're interested in the figure caption, title, subtitle, whatever, and the figure should wrap all of this. The figure tag is not limited to images; it can contain text, video, audio, code blocks, anything as long as it's part of that "entity" in your document. So the following is a single figure:

[image: Example of figure]

Now, in documents like scientific papers you will often find stuff like this:

[image: pictures of animals]

Although each image makes sense by itself, they make more sense as a group as they are connected by some kind of relationship; sometimes even the order matters (i.e. series of steps, or photos of states something goes through). That's a "*sentence of figures*" and you want to mine them together or you'll lose valuable information.

Our mining algorithm would have to understand your website's content with some kind of natural-language-processing AI, or it could just gather the FIGURE tags you provide for it. The later is good semantics.

Summarizing, imagine you're the Google AI algorithm mining figures in your code. Write your figure tags to make this script's job easy.

Comment: I can't say, I got what you said completely, specially the ending half, but when I want my content to be indexed by robots as a single unit, maybe in order to make them searchable, I have to use figure, right?

Comment: yup, basically. When these tags first came out it was so that Web 3.0 would be "semantic" and AI would be able to extract and categorize contents, without you having to even visit websites (It never happened of course). Guess the downvotes come from people that don´t like how I make it sound: that HTML5 semantic containers are useless (yeah, not what is taught in school, guess it hurts a coder's pride).

Comment: Couldn't bots just search for img-elements? 

Comment: @Hudson that's what they did in the past, the problem is that you don't know which img elements are part of the actual page contents and which ones are just there for decoration / layout purposes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure):

> Usually a `<figure>` is an image, illustration, diagram, code snippet, etc., that is referenced in the main flow of a document, but that can be moved to another part of the document or to an appendix without affecting the main flow.

An example of this (based on one from that same MDN link) might be a code snippet that prints the parts of the browser's navigator in an article about that attribute. You don't need to know the exact code to print that information to understand what is in the `navigator`, but it can aid the reader's understanding.

Additionally, the `<figure>` tag allows use of the `<figcaption>` tag as a child, which is a convenient and accessible way to caption images.

Comment: I think I got it, when I have a content that's not a forming part of components of my section or article, I can use figure to say this content is subsection of this section not its components , but when that content belongs to specific PART of my section or article I can't, when there is reference I have to use label reference which is identified by figcaption and when there is no reference I can use no figcaption, did I get it right?

Comment: That's the gist of it. However, `<figcaption>` doesn't reference the figure from the main content. The `<figcaption>` is a description of the image in `<figure>` -- literally a child of `<figure>` --  which is attached to that image, i.e. a caption. For example, if you had a scientific paper with a diagram, you could write in the paper "See figure 1 for details" . The `<figcaption>` would then say "Figure 1: A Scientific Diagram".

Comment: Yeah, and If I want that specific content to be indexed by robots, I have to manage to make that content to be part of that section or article directly, not part of elements which are components of that section or article.